# Azure devops pipeline with multiple repositories failing if the branch not present in the repo

Tags: azure-devops, multiple-repositories

I have parametrised the repository and branch name in repositories section of my multi repo pipeline, so that one pipeline will be used to build and deploy any repository or branch name user gives. But when the branch name specified is not present any other repository mentioned in the pipeline it’s giving error.

```
Parameters:
- Name: codeRepoName
  Type: string
- Name: branchName
  Type: string
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repoOne
    type: git
    ref: ${{parameter.branchName}}
    name: repoOne
  - repository: repoTwo
    type: git
    ref: ${{parameter.branchName}}
    name: repoTwo
     
/* multiple repos listed */
    
Checkout: ${{ parameter.codeRepoName }}
     
/* build and deploy stages */
```

If the specified branch name is present in all the repos pipeline will work if the branch name is not present in any one of the repositories the pipeline will fail.

I just need pipeline to run on specified repo and branch name, even though branch is not present in other repos.

Comment: How do you expect that to work? If the branch isn't present in the repo, the resource definition is invalid. You know that you can already choose the branch to run the pipeline against at queue time by clicking on the `resources` header when queuing the pipeline, right?

Comment: Any workaround for this issue, pipeline failing as soon as I run it and not at checkout step, I believe it’s doing a pre check on all the listed repos and branch. Or any other solution. Basically am looking for a single pipeline to build and deploy the repo and branch name specified by the user. Appreciate your help

Comment: I don't see how your proposed solution would work. You're using the same `name` for two repositories, which would mean that the unique identifier you're using isn't even unique. I explained above that you don't need to specify parameters, you can choose the branch to run for on the `resources` tab at queue time. The `ref` is the *default* branch to use if you don't override it.

Comment: Alright have edited the code for more clarity, when user specifies the repo and branch name, checkout is happening only on the given repo but only if branch is present in all the repo listed else it’s not going into the checkout section at all, at the start only it gives error branch not present.hope this gives more clarity of my issue

Comment: Problem is even though in checkout have passed only one codeRepoName, its doing some kind of pre check on all the repos mentioned and failing for which ever repo doesn’t have the specified branch

Comment: I've said this twice already so please let me know if you don't understand what I'm saying: You **don't need to specify parameters for branch name**, you can **choose the branch to run** for on the resources tab at queue time.